# Configuring consumerWindowSize in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

ActiveMQ Artemis configuration file in Spring Boot below:

```
spring:
  artemis:
    host: localhost
    port: 61616
    user: admin
    password: admin123
```

There is no properties for broker-url so that I can set `consumerWindowSize` like

```
tcp://localhost:61616?consumerWindowSize=0`
```

How can i configured `consumerWindowSize` in a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html) (which references [`ArtemisProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisProperties.java)) I don't believe you can set the broker's actual URL or any of the properties associated with it. This is a pretty serious short-coming of the Artemis Spring Boot integration as it really limits the configuration. There is already [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10739) open to (hopefully) address this.

Answer (score 0):

Added below configuration to solve this issue:

```
@Bean("connectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(AppProperties appProperties) {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory($brokerUrl);
        cf.setUser($user);
        cf.setPassword($password);
        return cf;
    }
```

Comment: I wonder how I could do this when embedded artemis is used for automated tests?